# CultureInfo differences between IIS and IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm having some problems with CultureInfo values for a specific culture, "pt-PT". To narrow it down I created an MVC project in VS 2017 using .net framework and added the following line to the view About.cshtml:

```
<p>@(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-PT").DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)</p>
```

This was the only change I made to the project created by visual studio.

When I run this project in VS using the IIS Express, the value returned by **FirstDayOfWeek** is 'Monday'.

However if I run this project in IIS (on the same machine), the value returned by **FirstDayOfWeek** is 'Sunday'.

I was expecting the value to be the same and to be 'Monday'.
I'm puzzled about the diference in values and would like some help in understanding it.

**Note:** After further tests I concluded that if I change the first day of the week in my computer settings, that change is reflected when running the project in IIS Express. I'm more confused... I guess this property is useless...

Comment: Could it be that IIS Express uses the Location settings from your user profile and IIS uses the Location settings from the default user?

Answer (score 1):

By default, IIS uses [`DateTimeInfo.InvariantInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.invariantinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns `Sunday` as its `FirstDayOfWeek` value (also using United States date format too). If you're unsure why IIS (not Express) uses different culture than you're using, set the culture information in `Application_BeginRequest` handler inside Global.asax code:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string culture = "pt";
     if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.Contains("pt"))
     {
         culture = "pt"; // Portuguese, use 'pt-PT' if not sure
     }
     else
     {
         // set to other cultures, including invariant (default) one
     }

     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture);
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
}
```

Or use `globalization` element in web.config file to set `Thread.Culture` & `Thread.UICulture`:

```
<globalization culture="pt-PT" uiCulture="pt" />
```

If all of the above settings doesn't work, use these steps below:

> 1. Open IIS Manager, select your site and open ".NET Globalization".
> 2. Open "Culture" tab, set both Culture & UI Culture section to Portuguese.
> 3. Restart the application pool or use `iisreset` command to apply all changes.

NB: As a general convention, the site shouldn't rely on server's application pool setup to work as expected with specified locale/culture. See [Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(v=vs.140).aspx) for further details about culture settings.

Also check if the regional settings of your application pool set to follow `NetworkService`'s user account, change it to `LocalSystem` if necessary.

Similar issues:

[ASP.NET Application is displaying american date formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402104/asp-net-application-is-displaying-american-date-formats)

[How do you set the IIS Application Pool Identity User Locale when it's set to ApplicationPoolIdentity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131443/how-do-you-set-the-iis-application-pool-identity-user-locale-when-its-set-to-ap)

Comment: I believe you are answering to a slightly different question. My question is that an object of type CultureInfo when created as `new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-PT")` as different property values when running in IIS and in IIS Express. I have experimented your suggestions and the behaviour remais the same.